# Perform regex on an specific item in list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Need a hand on implementing the below:

I've the below line in my list.

```
item =  ['0', '58s', '8us', '11s', '13ms', '176us', '320ms', '89us']
```

I want to perform check on item[6]. The logic should check, if item[6] contains the string 'us' or 'ms' the logic should. If it has either 'us' or 'ms', it should print 'Good' else it should print the item[6].

Comment: You need quotes around the list elements that aren't numbers.

Comment: You don't need a regexp. `if 'us' in item[6] or 'ms' in item[6]:`

Comment: You could also use `endswith`: `if item[6].endswith(('us', 'ms'))`

Comment: endswith worked for my usecase. I'll accept this as answer. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt function `any` to literally check if any of the elements are contained in a interable, its also efficient as it does not go through the whole list as `any` works when the first `Truth` is found. Additionally you are able to add elements to find for if required.

```
item =  '0    158s    48us     11s    13ms   176us   320ms    89us'.split()
find_for = ['ms','us']

if any(x in item[6] for x in find_for):
    print('Good!')
```